# WebApi HttpClient for .NET framework 3.5

Tags: wcf, rest, wcf-web-api

Is there any package available of WebApi for .Net framework 3.5? I'm specifically looking forward to use HttpClient component of WebApi.

Is there any alternatives that work on .Net 3.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very mature and very robust library that you can use for HTTP Requests is [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/). It has support for OAuth, pluggable serialization, and other HTTP concerns. It supports NET 3.5+, Silverlight 4, Windows Phone 7, Mono, MonoTouch.

It's open source and available via github. Here is a [blog post](http://www.collectivematters.com/2012/04/consuming-asp-net-web-api-with-restsharp/) about consuming WebAPI services with RestSharp. Check it out

Answer (score 3):

You can use http://www.servicestack.net/ client for this. And it works ok with Nuget=)